# How to get content between div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one ul li list and I want to put that content between ..

What I have

```
<div id='a'>
 <ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

what I want to do is that using jquery I want to add div before and after this content like this

What I want

```
<div id='a'>
<div id='b'>
 <ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

What I am using is append or before but not getting properly result.
I used following code.

```
$("#a").prepend("<div id='b'>");
$("#a").append("</div>");
```

But I got result like this.

```
<div id='a'>
<div id='b'></div>
 <ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to do this:

```
$("ul").wrap("<div id='b'></div>");
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADcWs/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `wrap()`

This will exactly do what you want:

```
$("#a > ul").wrap("<div id='b'></div>");
```

Look at the doc: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`$("ul").wrap("<div id='b'></div>");` and here is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FSvyW/)